# Find what functionality is bound to a child through event delegation

Tags: javascript, jquery, event-handling, event-delegation

if I delegate an event to an ancestor with something like

```
$("#container").on("click", ".distant_child", function(){

    //...

}
```

when I look in the developer tools in Chrome to see what click events are bound, I only see `#container`'s events. Is there any way to see what particular function is bound to a specific element?

Comment: That delegated event *is* only bound to the `#container` element. The jQuery selector is run at event time to filter the bubbled-event elements.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming I am not misunderstanding your question, as which *specific element* you mean is not clear, that delegated event *is* only bound to the `#container` element. The jQuery selector is run at event time to filter the bubbled-event elements.

Delegated events work by listening for events bubbling up to a non-changing ancestor element. It *then* applies the jQuery selector against the elements that caused the event to decide what elements to run the function against.

This delegation to an ancestor allows you to process events for elements that do not even exist at event registration time (a very useful thing).

Chrome will never see events on `.distant-child` elements as they have no event handler attached to them.

Answer (score 0):

If you are looking for listing delegated events too, if these events are bound using jQuery, you could iterate through `$._data` events object of element itself and ancestors. eg:

```
var arrayEvents = [];

$('#child').parents().addBack().add(document).each(function () {
    if (events = $._data(this, 'events')) {
        for (event in events) {
            for (var i = 0, z = events[event].length; i < z; i++)
            if ($('#child').is(events[event][i].selector)) arrayEvents.push({
                elem: this,
                event: events[event][i].type
            });
        }
    }
});
```

### -DEMO-